# EF 5 Composite Primary Key (won't work for some reason)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am aware this may be a duplicate question, but I've tried using the answers provided to similar questions and I've not had any success.

The situation is as follows: I'm creating a virtual bank for a school project and in the first prototype I simply want an Account table and a Transactions table. The relation between Transaction and Account is that every Transaction references two Accounts (From and To) and Account has 0...n Transactions.

The code I've been using:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("From")]
    public int FromID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("To")]
    public int ToID { get; set; }

    public float Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Account From { get; set; }

    public virtual Account To { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Balance { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("From")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> FromTransactions { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("To")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> ToTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

I have used `[Column(Order = 0)]` and `[Column(Order = 1)]` which should have resolved the problem, but VS still shows the message:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Bank_API.Models.Account'. Unable to
determine the composite primary key ordering for type
'Bank_API.Models.Transactions'. Use the ColumnAttribute or the HasKey
method to specify an order for composite primary keys.
```

This is my first time using ASP.NET or EF, so please be gentle.

P.S. I'm using .NET 4.6.1 and EF 5.

Comment: Not hundred percent sure, but the problem could be caused by the different type used for `Account` PK `ID` column (string) and `Transaction` `FromId`/`ToId` columns (int)

Comment: Try use correctly property names as `AccountId` and change `id` type to int. Also i think you need to apply `[Key]` attribute to `id` property  to create a primary key for.

Comment: Thanks to you both, the issue regarding string <-> int has been resolved, but it did not resolve the problem at hand. Also, adding [Key] to the ID field in Account did not seem to make a difference (I'm pretty sure that an integer field with the name ID is the primary key by default, as I've read)

Comment: What if you use correctly names : `AccountId` , `FromId`, `ToId`? You also set attribute `[Key]` to `FromId` and `ToId` , consider add `TransactionId` with `[Key]` attribute only.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I've considered the suggestion to use TransactionId as a primary key only, which would make a lot of sense in this situation, as two Accounts may have multiple transactions with each other... For some reason it still gives the error message, so I'm starting to suspect there's a different reason why this is not working... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have different type of key in Transaction and Account. Try to change to:

```
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

You can also make Fluent API to know that you want composite key like that:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasKey(x => new { x.FromID, x.ToID });
}
```

This override method should be in your DbContext class.
Also Attribute ForeignKey should be up of your virtual Account not Key like you do:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key]
    public int FromID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), Key]
    public int ToID { get; set; }

    public float Amount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FromID")]
    public virtual Account From { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ToID")]
    public virtual Account To { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this modelBuilder line? Also, thanks for noticing the int/string problem, I hadn't noticed that somehow! It did not fix the issue at hand, though.

Comment: Where can I find the DbContext class? I was making a Controller + Context class when I got this error, if that helps.

Comment: Your context class should derived from DbContext so that is the place where you should put this.

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that I never got to the point of having the Context class, as this error message would show while making it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to resolve the issue using your input and building the code before attempting to make the Controller based on the Account model. (I would've thought that if VS needed the code to build before creating the Controller it would do it automatically or at least notify me about it!)